# How to modify the default stylesheet?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

Each time I create a new notebook, I have to set the magnification to 150% and modify the output color to blue.

Is there a way to automate this using stylesheets or other features?

Comment: I also want to change default font.

Comment: Changing the default font is slightly tricky.  For text & titles, simply modify your default stylesheet.  For changes to more fundamental (for want of a better term) such as those used for In & Out, you'll have to modify Core.nb.

Comment: Could you tell me how? How to modify Core.nb to change output color and font ?

Comment: Same as normal.  The complication is that it's a system-owned file so you'll need to change ownership.  I'd recommend saving a pristine copy before changing anything.

Comment: I opened the file, use "format" menu to change text and color but changes are not taking effect.

Comment: If I add manually the following line to core.nb I get startup error:

 FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1],

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify default magnification very easily.

Open a new notebook.  Open the Option inspector (Format->Option inspector).  Select "Global preferences" in the first dialogue box, the move to Notebook options, then to display.  There's an option here called Magnification which can be set to what you want. Apply, quit, then your new default magnification should be visible when next you start.

What do you mean 'output colour'?

You can modify a style sheet to have whatever (ish) style you want.

Go to Format->edit stylesheet from the menu.  Choose an appropriate style to modify from the list.

Stylesheets are not documented particularly well.  David Park has a [guide for v6.0](http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/Mathematica.html) that's still relevant today.  There is also a more recent discussion in [Mathgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/d3b6923122fbd93e/8882d50149381d4d?lnk=gst&q=install%20style#8882d50149381d4d) that covers installation in MMA8.

There's a comment form John Fultz in [MathGroup](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/7c87a1d6858ff99b/f22180731ead38f7?lnk=gst&q=Annetts%20font#f22180731ead38f7) that "The font for StandardForm Input and Output cells comes from the StandardForm style.  Similarly, the font for InputForm cells comes from the InputForm style, and for OutputForm cells from the OutputForm style. 
There is a comment in Core.nb in the group that contains the Input/Output styles 
which mentions this."

Regards,

Dave.

Comment: Thanks for the Magnification. 

I am referring to the output text color. Yes, I know how to change it. But every time I have to choose the stylesheet from the "Format" menu. Is there a way to set a default stylesheet instead of selecting it each time ?

Comment: Absolutely.  Options inspector->Global preferences->Global options->File locations.  You want DefaultStyleDefinitions to point to your preferred definitions.

Comment: Where are the "Stylesheets" saved by default? I cannot locate the one I created.

Comment: But the stylesheet I saved is not there, but it appears in the menu.

Comment: System stylesheets are in ToFileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "StyleSheets"}].  Your own stylesheets are typically in ToFileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "StyleSheets"}]

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to change the OUTPUT "font type" ?

Comment: When I try to change LabelStyle in GraphicBoxOptions to for example Red I get the error "An improperly formatted directive with head Symbol was encountered." Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Look [there](https://cosmosimple.blogspot.ru/2014/01/change-default-stylesheet-in-mathematica.html):

(1) Open a notebook, in the menu choose "Format" -> "Edit Stylesheet".

(2) Choose a style to change. For example, "Text", in the menu at the top left.

(3) Modify fonts, etc.

(4) Save this stylesheet to a .nb file. Optionally one can also click Install StyleSheet so that the stylesheet can be found at "Format" -> "Stylesheet..." menu.

(5) Open menu "Format" -> "Option Inspector", make sure "Global Preference" is selected (where the default is "Selection") in the popup menu.

(6) Search for DefaultStyleDefinitions, change it to the saved stylesheet file. Click apply.

Close Mathematica and launch it again. The default font is changed.